# Verilog netlist synthesis using assign vs always

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis, synthesizer

If you have some sort of Verilog implementation like:

```
module Example1 (input logic n);

   always @(*) begin
      a <= n;
      b <= n;
      c <= n;
   end

endmodule;
```

and another implementation like:

```
module Exmaple2 (input logic n);

   assign a = n;
   assign b = n;
   assign c = n;

endmodule;
```

Is the synthesis algorithm that Verilog runs going to create the same netlist for each circuit?

I am under the impression the synthesizer is able to simplify logic somehow, and in my understanding the above two examples are essentially identical.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  This question specifically asks about synthesis, which is not discussed in the "duplicate" question or its answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your synthesis tool is likely to synthesize both code examples into the same logic.  The same [synthesis constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs) can be represented using different coding styles; the same is true for simulation behavior.

Both styles you show are intended to represent combinational logic.  In your 1st example, you use a procedural `always` block, where it is more customary to use blocking assignments (`=`) than nonblocking (`<=`):

```
module Example1 (input logic n);
   logic a, b, c;
   always @(*) begin
      a = n;
      b = n;
      c = n;
   end
endmodule
```

I realize you are only posting incomplete pseudocode, but the semicolon after `endmodule` is illegal syntax and should produce a compile error.